# Why does operator new need constructor to be public?

Tags: c++, constructor, new-operator

I was trying to find the relationship between `operator new` and `constructor`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Foo {
public:
        void* operator new(size_t t) {
                cout << "new()" << endl;
        }
        void operator delete(void* ptr) {
        }
        Foo() {
                cout << "constructor()" << endl;
        }
};
int main() {
        Foo* f = new Foo();
        delete f;
        return 0;
}
```

Here's the output.

```
new()
constructor()
```

It seems like `constructor` is called by `operator new` right? Then I set `constructor` private.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Foo {
public:
    void* operator new(size_t t) {
        cout << "new()" << endl;
    }
    void operator delete(void* ptr) {
    }
private:
    Foo() {
        cout << "constructor()" << endl;
    }
};
int main() {
    Foo* f = new Foo();
    delete f;
    return 0;
}
```

And I got a compilation error

```
root# g++ main.cpp 
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:13: error: ‘Foo::Foo()’ is private
main.cpp:19: error: within this context
```

Why can't `operator new` call private `constructor`, just like Singleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems like constructor is called by `operator new` right?

No. `new Foo()` is [new expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), which attempts to allocate storage (via `operator new`) and then attempts to construct the object (via the constructor of `Foo`). So the object is constructed from the context of `main()`, which can't access the constructor of `Foo` and causes the error. For instance if you make `main()` the `friend` of `Foo` it'll compile fine.